# Selenium WebElements difficulty

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am currently working on a program that permit to connect directly to some social network. Here is the code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com") 

username = "Richard"

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com')
input_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//input[@name='username']"
)

action=ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(input_username)
action.click()
action.send_keys(username)
action.perform()
```

And I got a problem because I got this error:

```
AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement
```

What can I do to resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input_username` is not a WebElement, but a list as you've used `find_elements_by_xpath()` instead of `find_element_by_xpath()`.

Try either

```
input_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
action.move_to_element(input_username)
```

or

```
input_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
action.move_to_element(input_username[0])
```

Note that Authentication form generated dynamically by JavaScript, so to be able to handle input fields, you need to wait for JavaScript to be executed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

input_username = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))
```

Comment: I try both but I got a problem. When I say input_username[0], they sey the list is out of range. So I check the list and she is empty.. What do I do ?

Comment: Welcome! You should also try to skip using Actions. `input_username.send_keys(username)` should work as well